# Very Frustrating Sandboxing Error

Tags: macos, xcode7, code-signing, osx-elcapitan, code-signing-entitlements

To preface, I haven't changed any code or entitlements in my app. It always built and worked great but now all of a sudden I am getting this error.

> 12/8/15 10:05:45.388 AM appleeventsd[51]:  A
>   sandboxed application with pid 2414, "XXX" checked in with
>   appleeventsd, but its code signature could not be read and validated
>   by appleeventsd, and so it cannot receive AppleEvents targeted by
>   name, bundle id, or signature. Install the application in
>   /Applications/ or some other world readable location to resolve this
>   issue. Error=ERROR: #100013  {
>   "NSDescription"="SecCodeCopySigningInformation() returned 100013, -."
>   }  (handleMessage()/appleEventsD.cp #2098) com.apple.root.default-qos

I have tried the following

1. Install the app in "Applications" as the error suggest.
2. Restart the computer.
3. Delete the container and empty the trash.
4. Killing off cfprefsd. Both root and user.
5. Re-installing Xcode.
6. Removing the "Developer" folder in my Library.
7. Running the app in a virtual machine with a brand new install of my app.
8. Recreate all my developer certificates, provisioning profiles, etc...

None of the above works.

I have also tried all suggestions in the following links

- [Mac sandbox created but no NSUserDefaults plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22242106/mac-sandbox-created-but-no-nsuserdefaults-plist)
- [Error while implementing Sandbox: "deny file-read-metadata /Library"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723074/error-while-implementing-sandbox-deny-file-read-metadata-library)
- [Can't code sign helper app properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707136/cant-code-sign-helper-app-properly)
- [Error in Sandboxed App, When loading Helper (LoginItems), code signing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18378574/error-in-sandboxed-app-when-loading-helper-loginitems-code-signing-issue)

And nothing has resolved the issue. My app, all of a sudden stopped working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I re-wrote the code for creating a security scoped bookmark... all is working again. I couldn't find any differences but I think it was something in my code.